# Error While Adding Cordova Plugin "sqlite-connector.jar" not found!"

Tags: sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

Error While Adding Sqlite plugin into Ionic project How to solve this?
Thanks in advance

- Command

  - cordova plugin add https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin.git
- Error:

  - Error: Uh oh!
    /project-path/plugins/cordova-sqlite-storage/node_modules/cordova-sqlite-storage-dependencies/libs/sqlite-connector.jar" not found!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont install like this, use

```
ionic plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage
```

Also you need to have installed nodejs globally to allow node-modules to be installed via npm, as seen in their doc

> This version uses a before_plugin_install hook to install sqlite3
>   library dependencies from cordova-sqlite-storage-dependencies via npm.

Comment: My Mistake is i dint add sqlite3 thank u very much Del

Comment: glad to know :) happy coding!

Comment: Hi, could you tell us how did you install sqlite3? is it something like this npm install sqlite3?

Comment: Agree with @NourdineAlouane this would be very helpful. Please update if known.

Answer (score 0):

try this

"cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage"